# Angular test jasmine, ng-mocks

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine, karma-runner, ng-mocks

I don't understand why my service is not getting called..
in my BooklistComponent, I call ngOnInit which calls initBooks() which calls the
bookApiService getAll() method...
My Setup:

```
 beforeEach(
      waitForAsync(() => {
          TestBed.configureTestingModule({
              declarations: [BookListComponent, BookCardComponent],
              imports: [
                HttpClientTestingModule
              ],
              providers: [
                BookApiService,
              //  MockProvider(BookApiService, {
              //   getAll: () => of<Book[]>([
              //     {
              //       title:"test",
              //       author: "Test",
              //       description: "hi",
              //       cover: 'empty',
              //       isbn: '12345',
              //       abstract: "test"
              //     }
              //   ]),
              //  })
              ],
          }).compileComponents();

      }));
```

const bookResolved = [{...}];

```
 it('should call BookApiService getAll()', () => {
        const spy_BookApiService_getAll = MockInstance(BookApiService, 'getAll', jasmine.createSpy('BookApiService.getAll')).and.returnValue(of(bookResolved));
        const bookList = MockRender(BookListComponent).point.componentInstance;
        bookList.ngOnInit();
        expect(spy_BookApiService_getAll).toHaveBeenCalled();
      })
```

The getAll() method is called in the ngOnInit() method in the BookComponent:

```
export class BookListComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  books$!: Observable<Book[]>;
  books!: Book[];
  private sub?: Subscription;

  constructor(private readonly bookApiService: BookApiService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.initBooks();
  
  }

  initBooks() {
    this.books$ = this.bookApiService.getAll();
  }....
```

Comment: Could you share how `.getAll()` is called in the component?

Comment: It works: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-qyzfvl-fhjink?file=src%2Ftest.spec.ts, I think your description is missing something.

Comment: Hi @Marc_L, have you solved the problem?

Comment: hi yes, it worked after I replaced the returnValueOf... with `and.callThrough()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix is to call the initial code of `BookApiService.getAll` despite the installed mock on it:

```
const spy_BookApiService_getAll =
  MockInstance(BookApiService, 'getAll', jasmine.createSpy())
    .and.callThrough(); // <-- instead of `returnValue`.
```